# How to execute one command on all files within a folder

Tags: shell, command-line, files, command

Saying, I have this tree and I want to execute `ruby` on all scripts within the folder. How could I archive through **one line of command**.

```
./
../
rb-script/
    sample1.rb
    sample2.rb
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something along the lines (depending on your shell) of

```
for file in rb-script/*.rb; do ruby "$file"; done
```

should do the trick; alternatively (and shell-independently, I think)

```
find rb-script -type f -exec ruby "{}" \;
```

using `find`; where you can, depending on your situation, be more specific, à la

```
find rb-script -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.rb' -exec ruby "{}" \;
```

In general, `command <glob-pattern>` would also work if `command` accepts several files (and there are less files than the commandline argument maximum of your shell), but I doubt `ruby` does that.  (You could write a wrapper script such that `ruby-wrapper rb-script/*.rb` would do what you want, though.)

Comment: Thanks. Good tips for using `;` to execute multiple commands.

Comment: The `for file in` works like a charm! Is there a way to make the loop run on these files sorted by name?

Answer (score 1):

If this will be part of a daemon, you could use the [run-parts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/run-parts.8.html) command to execute everything in the folder in alphabetical order. This command is especially useful if you need to execute it in reverse order for shutdown.